# Mail app and templates for emails?

Tags: snow-leopard, mail.app, email

I used Mail as my main mail client on Snow Leopard. It would be really useful to manage mail templates with it. I used to send similar emails every day and I need to create 20 or 30 email templates to used whenever I need.

How can I accomplish with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By templates I think you mean **canned messages**. Here's a workaround ([source](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/How_to_Save_and_Use_Messages_as_Templates_in_Mac_OS_X_Mail.htm)):

- Create a "Templates" folder.
- Create and save a new draft message (including title).
- Move the draft to "Templates" folder.
- Whenever you need to use that template select a message and then choose *Send Again* from the Messages menu.
- Make necessary modification and send.

Comment: I am unable to find an option for "Send Again."

Comment: @SAP995: It's in the Message menu. Try Shift+Cmd+D.